# addSubview don't display toolbar top and bottom

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I have something like that :

(1) NavigationController --> (2) UITableViewController --> (3 afted clicked in a cell) UIViewController

So when I receive a push notification, I want to redirect in the view controller ( which display a message )

I'm doing something like :

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    _messageConsult = (MessageConsultDetailViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"seeMoreView"];

_messageConsult.idMessage = [[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] objectForKey:@"id_message"];   
_messageConsult.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
self.window.rootViewController = _messageConsult;
[self.window addSubview:_messageConsult.view];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

So it display the view well, but without any top/bottom bar. Althought when i'm displaying the view directly from the UITableViewCell, it works

Someone can give me some advice to this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't see it because you're instantiating a new instance of MessageConsultDetailViewController and making that your window's root view controller -- that means, it will be the only view controller in the hierarchy, and the navigation controller(with its navigation and tool bars)and table view controller will be deallocated if you don't have any strong pointers to them. The correct way to display that controller would be to do a push from the table view controller.

By the way, when you make a controller the window's root view controller, you shouldn't also add its view as a subview to the window -- that's already done when you make it the root view controller.

Comment: Shouldn't he push from the navigation controller not a tableView?  `[self.navigationController pushViewController: _messageConsult]`